# calling javascript in another file in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to override the `onClosing` event in a QML application window.

The qml for the window is simple as:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    objectName: "window"
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480

    property Component loginForm: LoginView {}

    onClosing: {
        loginForm.logout()
    }
}
```

The `LoginView` view is simple as well:

```
Rectangle {
    id: view    
    function logout() {
        console.log("Logout called");
    }
}
```

Now, as is, it returns an error:

```
TypeError: Property 'logout' of object QQmlComponent(0x9287150) is not a function
```

I also tried `loginForm.view.logout()` and this returns in:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'logout' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe QML is having trouble because your property is of type `Component`.  You are assigning a `LoginView`, which is an inheritance descendent of `Component`, to a property of type `Component`.  If you change your property to be of type `LoginView`, it will work:

```
property LoginView loginForm : LoginView{}
```

If this isn't actually a property that you want to be exported by the main module, you can simply instantiate it without creating a property, but still giving it a module-scope identifier:

```
LoginView{ id: loginForm }
```

Doing either of these will give you access to that function.

Comment: Ahhhhh....Thanks for that! Yes, of course, it loses the specific information due to the cast to the generic component type...

Comment: QML has got some funk to it.  This tutorial was very helpful for me in the beginning: http://qmlbook.github.io/

Comment: @Luca I think it would have worked with a generic type as well, i.e. `Item` or `QtObject`. `Component` is a "class" definition, not an instance